# Opening fancybox after a [HTTP POST] when a field is higher as 15

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

**Situation:**

We open the first fancybox where the user fills in basic data like date , time, location.

After that post we open a 2nd fancybox window that allows the user to fill in some details. Like amount, groupname , e-mail etc. We autmaticly create other hours when the amount is above 15 and 30 when the location = X , 30 and 60 when the location = Y.

But if that amount is above the max allowed on a day. It needs to open a 3rd fancybox that allows the user to fill in an extra date for the other persons.

**Question:**

The question is how do I let the fancybox open when the amount field of the 2nd fancybox is higher as a certain number. That certain number depends on a field on the first page.

**Code:**

```
function closeFancyGroepAndIndi() {

    $.fancybox.close();

// this would always open that page
//    $.fancybox({
//        'type': 'ajax',
//        'ajax': { cache: false },
//        'href': ResolveUrl('~/Groep/CreateDouble')

//    });

// reloads the main tables. This should only be the case when the amount is not higher.
    $("#reservationList").load(ResolveUrl('~/Reservation/reservationList'));
    if ($("#indexGroep") && $("#indexIndividual")) {
        var id = $("#reservationId").val();
        $("#indexGroep").load(ResolveUrl('~/Reservation/groepList'), { reservationId: id });
        $("#indexIndividual").load(ResolveUrl('~/Reservation/individualList'), { reservationId: id });
    }
```

**Thoughts so far:**

I thought to check for the value in the in the 2nd page it's javascript but then I have to give the value in 3rd fancybox to a hiddenfield.
the checking of the values will happen with.
leftOverAmount = $('#AmountHidden').val(); and maxAmount = $('maxAmountHidden').val();

So how do I get that location of my first page in the 2nd page his javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I use this value in more than one place. It was already defined in my web.config

So I use this in my view

```
 var appSetting = '@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxAmount"].ToString())'
```

and call the appSetting from my partial view. And also changed the idea of an extra popup it was way to much. So now I'm going to show and hide fields when the amount is > maxAmount.

Answer (score 1):

Call a function on blur event of the textbox some thing like

Now as soon as user's enter any value and and tabbed to some different field, the javascript function will be called. With in that function, check the value of the textbox and if it is greater than desired value, then trigger your js function to open new pop up.

Mark if this answer is suitable for u

Cheers!

Comment: The problem is not showing the pop up or getting to the value of that page. The problem is getting the value of that first page in my second page it's javascript. So that I can check which location it is . Because each location needs an other maxAmount.

Comment: Do u want to get some value from ur parent page to child page? If yes, then from ur childPage u can call a function of ur parent page, which will return u the requested value, using window.parent.functionName

Comment: It are all partial pages. Non of the pages is  the parent page.

Comment: Couple of questions: 1. Using which Js API u r opening Popup? 2. Partial Page means r u opening usercontrols in a page, or Div or Iframe. 3. Set a global javascript variable in a partial page with some value, and in any other partial page just try to alert the vaiables value, and check whether u r getting the value of it or not?

Comment: 1. Fancybox as stated before 
2. A mvc 3 partial page @using Ajax.BeginForm
3. Indeed that's a good idea. Going to test that one today.

Thanks for taking the time to respond my answer. I'll tell you when this worked.